# Export a list from php to a TXT file

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple code where I genarate a list of random 4 digit words for a project using all the letters from the alphabet. But the problem is that the list is so large that it crashes the brownser. I would like to export this list to a txt file instead. Does anyone have any idea on how to do it?

I am new with PHP

```
 for($a=0; $a<26; $a++){
    for($b=0; $b<26; $b++){
        for($c=0; $c<26; $c++){
           for($d=0; $d<26; $d++){
             echo($_POST['input'].$alphabet[$a].$alphabet[$b].$alphabet[$c].$alphabet[$d].);
             echo("<br />");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Run your script on the command line. Four loops just take some time to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$input_data =   "";
 for($a=0; $a<26; $a++){
    for($b=0; $b<26; $b++){
        for($c=0; $c<26; $c++){
           for($d=0; $d<26; $d++){             
             $input_data    =   $_POST['input'].$alphabet[$i].$alphabet[$j].$alphabet[$k].$alphabet[$l]."\n";
             file_put_contents("some_file.txt",$input_data,FILE_APPEND);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your data will be stored in `some_file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use `put_file_contents()`

```
$string = "";
$file = 'mytext.txt'; //filename

for($a=0; $a<26; $a++){
    for($b=0; $b<26; $b++){
        for($c=0; $c<26; $c++){
           for($d=0; $d<26; $d++){
             $string .= $_POST['input'].$alphabet[$i].$alphabet[$j].$alphabet[$k].$alphabet[$l];
             $string .= "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}

file_put_contents($file, $string);
```